# Update Record from Form ListBox Selection in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, database, forms, ms-access

I'm creating a database for first time with some VBA and have successfully figured out all issues I've run into until now. However, I've now been stuck with this issue for a while and am seeking help!

I have a form where users can create new records for storage bundles that each have their own assigned unique ID (unrelated to the Primary Key ID). Each bundle/record has a status to indicate if it's Pending, Completed or Deleted (no records will ACTUALLY be deleted). When a new record is created, the status is automatically set to Pending. I have a query that shows the last 3 Pending status bundles created, and want to make this a subform on the main form for creation with a button where the user can select one of the last 3 Pending records and delete it where the status will simply change to Deleted and the subform requeries.

My issue is, I can't figure out how to make the Status column of the selected record in the listbox update, it always wants to update the last created record and not the selected one. Please note, my listbox is not a multi-select as I want the user to only be able to select one record to delete at a time.

```
Private Sub DeleteButton_Click()

    If IsNull(ListBox.Column(0)) Or IsEmpty(ListBox.Column(0)) Then
    MsgBox "Select an item first", vbCritical, "No Item Selected"
    Exit Sub
    End If
```

I have the above so far to prompt if there is no selection, but I'm unable to continue the code without knowing the line to select the related record of the query selected from the list box.

Comment: Is this listbox UNBOUND? Use the selection to fillter form or goto record or run an action SQL. Which do you prefer? It's not really clear to me how listbox and subform interact. If subform shows desired record and user selects that record, what purpose does listbox serve?

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking more into a listbox instead of a subform. The listbox is currently bound to a query that shows the last 3 Pending bundles. How can I make it so that after clicking a button, the selected and only the selected Record from the listbox will have its current "Pending" Status value changed to "Deleted"? Then refreshed.

Comment: You have to move to record on form and change that record or run UPDATE action SQL then Requery listbox.